# Starting new activity on android not pause current activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have started new  activity from current Activity:

> ```
>  public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>
>             .....
>
>             Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity, DetailsActivity.class);
>             MainActivity.startActivity(myIntent);
>
>           .......
> ```

and in current (old) activity I have loop :

> ```
>       while (running) {
>
>             this.gamePanel.update();
>            this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
>         }
> ```

after the starting nnew activity current activity is still running ? 
I have error in this loop from inside:

> this.gamePanel.render(canvas);

how to pause current activity after starting new activity?

Comment: You have to end the while loop

Comment: set `running = false` in your onPause of the Activity

Comment: but when i sart new activity i don't know, where in the loop is running. it coul be just before rendering.

Comment: and I want to continue loop after close second activity. From current place where this loop was stopped.

Comment: Where is that loop running? Main thread? New thread? A Handler?

Comment: the loop is in main thread

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new class :

```
public class newClass implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
         while (running) {
             this.gamePanel.update();
             this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

now you just need to start this Thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new newClass());
t.start();
```

if you want to switch to a new Activity you just set running = false right before starting the new Activity. If the Thread is currently running the while-Loop, he will finish running it and then stop.
Coming back from the other activity you just need to start this Thread again

Comment: and what i the loop is just executing update method?   I am starting new activity and the render method is going to start anyway. because trying is at the beggining of the loop.